# How do I use /summon to spawn a certain type of item in minecraft? (Such as colored wool)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to spawn an enchanted golden apple for a boost in my adventure map (in 1.9) but I end up summoning a normal golden apple. What kind of ID do I add to this:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:golden_apple}
```

To make it spawn an enchanted golden apple? This goes for a lot of things such as colored wool, different wood, all the kinds/variety of stone etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `Damage` short tag is what specifies metadata value. A metadata value of 1 is an enchanted golden apple:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:golden_apple",Damage:1,Count:1}}
```

Comment: seriously? damage

Comment: @Fennekin You shouldn't take the term `Damage` too literally. It is pretty much used as a tag where making a special tag for that purpose is too much of an overkill.

Comment: @Fennekin It originates in the time when only tools used the value. Then Mojang decided something like, "Hey, Instead of making 16 different wool blocks, let's just make one that looks different. We can figure out which one it is from the currently only-used-for-tools damage tag! Perfect!", which set a precedent of using Damage for lots of similar blocks and items.

Comment: .. until Minecraft 1.13, when Mojang reversed itself and split all of those hybrid items into separate IDs again.